# How to configure Vue router history mode in Apache

Tags: apache, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router, html5-history

I'm getting this error when I try to add the line below on my **/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf**:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
</IfModule>
```

> ```
> Syntax error on line 228 of /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf:
> RewriteBase: only valid in per-directory config files
> ```

I'm using Apache/2.4.6 (CentOS 8)

The only thing I changed in my httpd folder are:

> **/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf:**
>
> ```
> <VirtualHost *:80>
>     ServerName masterseller.ph
>     Redirect permanent / https://masterseller.ph
> </VirtualHost>
> ```

and

> **/etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf:**
>
> ```
> <VirtualHost *:443>
> DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/masterseller/dist/"
> ... (+ SSL configs)
> </VirtualHost>
> ```

Oh btw I'm trying to deploy my vue dist folder (which is also my DocumentRoot).

> **My Vue-Rounter**:
>
> ```
> const router = new VueRouter({
>      mode: "history", 
>      base: "/",
>      routes
> });
> ```

I'm trying to follow and understand this instruction:
https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/history-mode.html#example-server-configurations

I tried to add '**FallbackResource /index.html**' at the end of my httpd.conf file, It worked, but I wouldn't be able to access my phpmyadmin page.

What am I mising? I'm new to all this.

Thank you in advance for your answers (also my boss doesn't want the hash mode for the vue router)

Answer (score 2):

The error means the config won't work in the base config file.  In Apache you can also place a "per-directory" configuration in each directory.

Create a new `.htaccess` file in the `dist` root and place the configuration in it.

The `.htaccess` [Apache docs](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/howto/htaccess.html) say:

> `.htaccess` files (or "distributed configuration files") provide a way to make configuration changes on a per-directory basis. A file, containing one or more configuration directives, is placed in a particular document directory, and the directives apply to that directory, and all subdirectories thereof.